# How to pick top q elements in each row and each column in a Tensorflow tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am implementing a special loss function in Tensorflow. Here is the numpy-style code of a special function which picks top q elements and masks other elements in each row and each column. Note that `A` is a `n*n` matrix, and `q` is an integer less than `n`.

```py
def thresh(A, q):
    A_ = A.copy()
    n = A_.shape[1]
    for i in range(n):
        A_[i, :][A_[i, :].argsort()[0:n - q]] = 0
        A_[:, i][A_[:, i].argsort()[0:n - q]] = 0
    return A_
```

Now the problem is that I have a Tensorflow tensor `A` whose shape is `(n,n)`, and I would like to implement the same logic as numpy. However, I cannot use indices to assign values to the tensor `A` directly. Does anyont has some solutions about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TLDR;

We can create a function that masks all but the top `k` elements row wise as follows:

```py
def mask_all_but_top_k(X, k):
  n = X.shape[1]
  top_k_indices = tf.math.top_k(X, k).indices
  mask = tf.reduce_sum(tf.one_hot(top_k_indices, n), axis=1)
  return mask * X
```

Unfortunately `tf.map.top_k` does not let us specify the dimension but we can, of course, replicate this column wise by first transposing `X` then transposing the result with `tf.transpose()`

#### Explanation

We can get there by creating a mask of ones and zeros and then multiplying element-wise.

So, for example, considering the case where `n=4, k=2` and we have the following matrix:

```
array([[0.67757607, 0.74070597, 0.89508283, 0.11858773],
       [0.7661159 , 0.8737055 , 0.73599136, 0.1552105 ],
       [0.7093129 , 0.44203556, 0.48861897, 0.83231044],
       [0.24682868, 0.36648738, 0.92984104, 0.9881872 ]], dtype=float32)
```

then we can use the `tf.math.top_k` function to get the indices of the top 2 values in each row of the matrix:

```py
top_k_indices = tf.math.top_k(X, 2).indices
```

Now, we use a little trick to first `one_hot` encode these:

```
tf.one_hot(top_k_indices, 4)
array([[[0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [1., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 1.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0.]]], dtype=float32)>
```

then to `reduce_sum` them across the second to last dimension to create our mask:

```py
tf.reduce_sum(tf.one_hot(top_k_indices, 4), axis=1)
array([[0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 1.]], dtype=float32)>
```

now we can just do a Hadamard (element-wise) multiplication to get the desired result:

```
array([[0.        , 0.74070597, 0.89508283, 0.        ],
       [0.7661159 , 0.8737055 , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.7093129 , 0.        , 0.        , 0.83231044],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.92984104, 0.9881872 ]], dtype=float32)>
```

putting this all together we can create a function that masks all but the top `k` elements row wise as follows:

```
def mask_all_but_top_k(X, k):
  n = X.shape[1]
  top_k_indices = tf.math.top_k(X, k).indices
  mask = tf.reduce_sum(tf.one_hot(top_k_indices, n), axis=1)
  return mask * X
```